# Nest query to write must and should in bool

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to write query that will produce result like below. Bool query takes only a boolQueryDescriptior. I want to use two boolQueryDescriptors instead.

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "id": "idValue"
               }
            }
         ],
         "should": [
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "nestedType",
                  "query": {
                     "match": {
                        "item2": "item2Value"
                     }
                  },
                  "inner_hits": {}
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you only need the one descriptor! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, we need only one descriptor, that could be chained. I was trying && and ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var results = client.Search<object>(sd => sd
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(m => m
                .Term("id", "idValue"))
            .Should(s => s
                .Nested(nq => nq
                    .Path("nestedType")
                    .Query(qd => qd
                        .Match(m => m
                            .OnField("item2")
                            .Query("item2Value")))
                    .InnerHits()))));
```